# Host, PHP, htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, host

I need some help.

I was reading the security recommendations of my hosting service and they say that ideally just put the
index file and files like css, js and img inside my root folder, and that all other files should be placed
off, that is, a level above.

I tried doing this in my tests, and I had some problems. The structure of the hosting folders is:

/

/htdocs

Inside /htdocs I put the index.php file and when accessing it through the url exemple.com/index.php works normally.

But putting other test files out of htdocs is what starts the problem. For example, if I have a file called contact.php
and I try to access it through the url exemple.com/contact.php I get the 404 error message.

So the question I have to ask is:

Is it possible to access url files that are outside of htdocs, or better to put all the files that will be accessed by the url inside
of htdocs and leave only configuration files outside this folder, like class, functions, database connection, etc?

And if it is possible to access the files by url, how would I rewrite these urls in htaccess?

Comment: It sounds like `htdocs` is your web root folder.  So anything in that folder is your externally facing website.  Anything outside of that folder is not externally facing.  So by design you can't directly access files outside of the web root by a URL.

Comment: @David  Thanks for your comment. And yes, htdocs is my root folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and that all other files should be placed off

Yes, this is good practice. However, you're misunderstanding the implementation.

You can not directly access files outside the document root. But you can *indirectly* access them. I.e., the web server can't see them, but your programming code can.

Ideally, your site would use the [front controller](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/front-controller-design-pattern/) pattern. Here, your index.php file would serve every page of your app by intercepting every request and then routing it to the correct end point. I.e., you would never directly request `/contact.php`, you'd instead request `/contact`, which would get funneled to `/index.php`, which would load the required resources from outside the doc root.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. What you said is exactly what I was thinking of doing, but I came here to ask because I wanted the opinion of people with more experience than I did. And from your answer, I've seen that I'm on the right way. Thanks again for your help.